# How to specify names in LD with binary text?

Tags: c++, ld

I am attempting to wrap a text file with `ld` into a `.o`. Given how the Makefiles for my project are set up, the full path to the text file is being passed to `ld`. This causes the generated names to include that path. I don't want that as I can't link against that name in my C++ source.

Is there a way to change the names or prefixes when I run `ld`?

```
ld -r -b binary /path/to/source/Value.txt -o Value.o
objdump -x Value.o | grep binary
0000000000000142 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary__path_to_source_Value_txt_end
0000000000000142 g       *ABS*  0000000000000000 _binary__path_to_source_Value_txt_size
0000000000000000 g       .data  0000000000000000 _binary__path_to_source_Value_txt_start
```

I would like to see names like `_binary_Value_txt_end`.

Comment: _"I am attempting to wrap a text file with ld"_ That sounds like a pretty bad idea. Do you actually have something like compiled in _resouurce files_?

Comment: Perhaps I worded it poorly, but, yes, I'm trying to make a .o with a resource embedded in it to use from my C++ source, and I want controllable names.

Comment: I'm not sure, that what you have would really serve as a binary resource. Though, as you're stating _" I don't want that as I can't link against that name in my C++ source."_ You may try to use `extern "C"` declarations, to link against those symbols.

Comment: Have you tried something like `pushd path; ld [options]; popd`

Comment: `pushd; popd` worked wonderfully. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Captain Oblivious' comment, I was able to develop a Makefile rule:

```
%.o: %.txt
    pushd $(dir $<) ; $(LD) -r -b binary $(notdir $<) -o $@ ; popd
```

This changes to the directory location of the text file so that `ld` creates nice, known names. I needed to do some work to ensure that `$@` was an absolute path so the `.o` would be created in the build directory.